# Centering Text in Responsive Video Background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have some text centered within this video. I got rid of the container for the header, and the desired results are still in tact, so that works with me, but I've struggled to deal with centering this text!

```
<div class="video-container">


    <video class="video" preload="true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop = "loop">
            <source src="nyc.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>

    </video>
    <p class="center-block quote"> Test </p>
```

Styling:

```
.video-container {

position:absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%; /*centers the video */
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;

}



video {
margin-top:50px; /* gap b/w navbar and header */
position:absolute;
z-index: -1;
opacity: 0.78;
width: 100%;
margin: none;
padding: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here a print screen
[worked print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9vW8.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
 .center-block{text-align: center;}
.video-container {

position:absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%; /*centers the video */
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;

}



video {
margin-top:50px; /* gap b/w navbar and header */
position:absolute;
z-index: -1;
opacity: 0.78;
width: 100%;
margin: none;
padding: none;
}
</style>
<div class="video-container">


    <video class="video" preload="true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop = "loop">
            <source src="nyc.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>

    </video>
    <p class="center-block quote"> Test </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: print screen from your browser

Comment: It's not in the center of the picture, though, which is what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a built in helper class - .text-center

Try this: `<div class="video-container text-center">`

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
<p class="center-block quote" style="text-align:center;"> Test </p>
```

And also paste this one:

```css
.video-container {

position:relative;
top: 0%;
left: 0%; /*centers the video */
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.video-container video{ 
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
}

.video-container{  
  justify-content: centre;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: centre;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the text stays aligned, but the image is no longer responsive.

Comment: Do some media querying for responsiveness @RyanG